# Does Excel have a function to calculate Canadian federal holidays?

Tags: excel, date, vba

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the past/future Canadian federal holiday dates to use the `NETWORKDAYS` function in the cell. Because the dates of the holidays change every year, is there a function or VBA code that I can use to calculate this?

For example, I have a 10 year project and I want to calculate the variance between the beginning date and the end date, excluding the weekends and holidays.

Like, Civic holiday is on the 1st Monday of August. It was on the 1st in 2011, but in 2012 it was on the 6th.

Easter Monday was on the 25th in 2011, but on the 9th in 2012.

Becuase `NETWORKDAYS` need exact date of the holidays in order to work, I need to calculate the future holiday dates (10-15years into the future)

I hope this makes sense...

Comment: no. Excel's not likely to have such a thing, since holidays are different for every country and even down at the state/province level. As well, dates get fiddled by politicians. tracking such things to produce a "standard" holiday function would be a nightmare.

Comment: Make a list of holidays for different years as a reference for `NETWORKDAYS`?

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/holidays.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a list quite easily with a formula approach e.g.for Labour Day list years only in A2 down and in another column in row 2 use this formula

=DATE(A2,9,8)-WEEKDAY(DATE(A2,9,6))

that will give the date of First Monday in September for the relevant year - copy formula down column

Edit: Here's a [workbook](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3g4h9hzpkn687fs/Canada%20holidays.xls) with all holidays calculated from 2000 to 2099 as per your rules, I think. If you want dates before 2000 then just change the years in column A and the dates will change automatically

I would add a couple of blank columns to the range, e.g. make C2:M101 = holidays, then you can use that named range in any NETWORKDAYS/WORKDAY function - the extra columns would allow you to enter any "ad hoc" holidays

Comment: I don't quite understand the function above. In total there are 9 holidays in total. New years, Good Friday, Victoria Day, Canada Day (if July 1st is on sunday, July 2nd is off), Labour Monday, Thanksgiving, Remembrance Day, Christmas and Boxing day.

Comment: if, Remembrance is on the sunday, the Monday (12th) is off. 

Good Friday

Victoria Day:Monday Preceding May 25th
Canada Day: July 1st (If July 1st is on sunday, July 2nd is off)
Labour day: First Monday of September
Thanksgiving: Second Monday of October
Remembrance Day: If it's on Sunday, Monday is off
Christmas
Boxing Day

Is there a way to account these conditions?

Comment: That was just an example to calculate one n givee a moment and  I can do them all......

Comment: just going though these - I'll post an example shortly - Canada Day and Remembrance Day can be on Saturdays?

Comment: Hi Barry, for some reason the link doesn't open

Comment: Thank you Barry, I've got the file!

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm a little late to the thread but for some reason the link to your file doesn't open. I would love to see how you calculate the Canadian holidays. I have found solutions for: Labour Day, Easter, Good Friday and Victoria Day but still looking for the rest.

Labour Day
=DATE(A2,9,8)-WEEKDAY(DATE(A2,9,6))
Easter
=FLOOR("5/"&DAY(MINUTE(A2/38)/2+56)&"/"&A2,7)-34
Good Friday
=FLOOR(DATE(A2,5,DAY(MINUTE(A2/38)/2+56)),7)-36
Victoria Day
=DATE(A2,5,25)-WEEKDAY(DATE(A2,5,25),3)-(7*(WEEKDAY(DATE(A2,5,25),3)=0))
*** 4 digit year must be in A2 ***

Answer (score 0):

The working days are from Monday to Friday, excluding the holidays.

Some holidays taking place during weekend should be moved to next Monday (e.g. Canada Day, Boxing Day, New Year), or previous Friday (e.g. Christmas)

The following are the formulas for the holidays in the province of Ontario, Canada, if the fiscal year is in FYear

Holyday             Formula

New Year    =WORKDAY(DATE(FYear,1,0),1)

Family Day  =DATE(FYear,2,22)-WEEKDAY(DATE(FYear,2,6))

Good Friday =FLOOR(DATE(FYear,5,DAY(MINUTE(FYear/38)/2+56)),7)-36

Victoria Day    =DATE(FYear,5,25)-WEEKDAY(DATE(FYear,5,23))

Canada Day  =DATE(FYear,7,1)+(WEEKDAY(DATE(FYear,7,2))<3)*(3-WEEKDAY(DATE(FYear,7,2)))

CivicDay    =DATE(FYear,8,8)-WEEKDAY(DATE(FYear,8,6))

LaborDay    =DATE(FYear,9,8)-WEEKDAY(DATE(FYear,9,6))

Thanksgiving    =DATE(FYear,10,15)-WEEKDAY(DATE(FYear,10,6))

Christmas   =DATE(FYear,12,25)-(WEEKDAY(DATE(FYear,12,26))<3)*WEEKDAY(DATE(FYear,12,26))

Boxing Day  =DATE(FYear,12,26)+(WEEKDAY(DATE(FYear,12,27))<3)*(3-WEEKDAY(DATE(FYear,12,27)))

Next New Year   =WORKDAY(DATE(FYear+1,1,0),1)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I found this page very useful, but I have a couple of additions.  My use case is that I want to know when a stat holiday occurs even when it moves to a different day like Friday or Monday.  These formulas apply to a table where @Year contains the year as a simple number.

U.S. Independence day behaves differently.  If July 4 is a Saturday then the holiday is on 3 July.  If July 4 is a Sunday then the holiday is 5 July.  I found writing these as nested IF statements more straightforward:

`=IF(WEEKDAY(DATE([@Year],7,4))=7, DATE([@Year],7,3), IF(WEEKDAY(DATE([@Year],7,4))=1,DATE([@Year],7,5),DATE([@Year],7,4)))`

Next, the formulas above don't work for years like 2021 where Christmas and Boxing Day were a Saturday and Sunday.  Again I think nested IFs work better.

We know that if Christmas Day (Dec 25) is on a Saturday, then the stat holiday is on Dec 27, and if it is on a Sunday then the stat holiday is Dec 26.     `=IF(WEEKDAY(DATE([@Year],12,25))=7,DATE([@Year],12,27),IF(WEEKDAY(DATE([@Year],12,25))=1,DATE([@Year],12,26),DATE([@Year],12,25)))`

Similarly, we know that if Boxing Day is on either a Saturday or a Sunday (meaning Christmas was Saturday), then the stat is on Dec 28. And if it falls on a Monday (meaning Christmas was Sunday), then it moves to Dec 27.

`=IF(OR(WEEKDAY(DATE([@Year],12,26))=7,WEEKDAY(DATE([@Year],12,26))=1),DATE([@Year],12,28), IF(WEEKDAY(DATE([@Year],12,26))=2, DATE([@Year],12,27), DATE([@Year],12,26)))`